# The necessity for cleanup of "application lifetime" objects

Tags: c++

We've inherited large legacy application which is structured roughly like this:

```
class Application
{
    Foo* m_foo;
    Bar* m_bar;
    Baz* m_baz;

public:

    Foo* getFoo() { return m_foo; }
    Bar* getBar() { return m_bar; }
    Baz* getBaz() { return m_baz; }

    void Init()
    {
        m_foo = new Foo();
        m_bar = new Bar();
        m_baz = new Baz();

        // all of them are singletons, which can call each other
        // whenever they please
        // may have internal threads, open files, acquire
        // network resources, etc.
        SomeManager.Init(this);
        SomeOtherManager.Init(this);
        AnotherManager.Init(this);
        SomeManagerWrapper.Init(this);
        ManagerWrapperHelper.Init(this);
    }

    void Work()
    {
        SomeManagerWrapperHelperWhateverController.Start();

        // it will never finish
    }

    // no destructor, no cleanup
};
```

All managers once created stay there for the whole application lifetime. The application does not have close or shutdown methods and managers also doesn't have those. So, the complex inter dependencies are never dealt with.

The question is: if the objects lifetime is tightly coupled with the application lifetime, is it accepted practice to not have cleanup at all? Will the operating system (Windows in our case) be able to cleanup everything (kill threads, close open file handles, sockets, etc.) once the process ends (by ending it in task manager or by calling special functions like ExitProcess, Abort, etc.)? What are possible problems with the above approach?

Or more generic question: are destructors absolutely necessary for global objects (declared outside of main)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will the operating system (Windows in our case) be able to cleanup
>   everything (kill threads, close open file handles, sockets, etc.) once
>   the process ends (by ending it in task manager or by calling special
>   functions like ExitProcess, Abort, etc.)? What are possible problems
>   with the above approach?

As long as your objects aren't initialising any resources *not* cleaned up by the operating system, then it doesn't make any practical difference whether you explicitly clean up or not, as the OS will mop up for you when your process is terminated.

However, if your objects *are* creating resources which are not cleaned up by the OS then you've got a problem and need a destructor or some other explicit clean up code somewhere in your app.

Consider if one of those objects creates sessions on some remote service, like a database for example. Of course, the OS doesn't magically know that this has been done or how to clean them up when your process dies, so those sessions would remain open until something kills them (the DBMS itself probably, by enforcing some timeout threshold or other). Perhaps not a problem if your app is a tiny user of resources and you're running on a big infrastructure - but if your app creates and then orphans enough sessions then that resource contention on that remote service might start to become a problem.

> if the objects lifetime is tightly coupled with the application
>   lifetime, is it accepted practice to not have cleanup at all?

That's a matter of subjective debate. My personal preference is to include the explicit cleanup code and make each object I create personally responsible for cleaning up after itself wherever practical. If application-lifetime objects are ever refactored such that they no longer live for the lifetime of the object, I don't have to go back and figure out whether I need to add previously-omitted cleanup. I guess for cleanup I'm saying that I generally prefer to lean towards [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) over the more pragmatic [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it).

Comment: Thanks, the consideration of sessions seems like the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

> is it accepted practice to not have cleanup at all

It depends on who you're asking.

> Will the operating system (Windows in our case) be able to cleanup
>   everything (kill threads, close open file handles, sockets, etc.) once
>   the process ends

Yes, the OS will take back everything. It will claim memory, free handles etc.

> What are possible problems with the above approach

One of the possible problems is that if you use a memory leak detector it will constantly show you have leaks.

Comment: Shutdown memory leaks are probably not as critical in application code (though still annoying) if you use some script to filter those "false positive" from leak-checker output. But it's always a real problem with library code. I remember leak-checking a Qt application and getting hundreds of possible leaks in libfontconfig.

Answer (score 1):

In general, modern operating systems cleans up all a process resources on exit. But in my opinion it's still good manners to clean up after yourself. (But then I was "raised" on the Amiga, where you *had* to do it.)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's forced on you by a spec or just by the behaviour of 'peripherals'.  Perhaps you have a lot of data buffered in your app that should really be flushed to disk or maybe a DB may accumulate 'half-open' connections is not explicitly closed.

Other than that, as @cnicutar says, it depends who you ask.  I'm firmly in the 'don't bother' camp for the following reasons:

1) It's difficult enough to get apps to work anyway without writing extra shutdown code that is not required.

2) The more code you write, the more bugs there are and the more testing you have to do.  You may have to test such code in more than one OS version:(

3) The OS developers have spent a long time ensuring that apps can always be shut down if required, (eg. by Task Manger), without any overall impact on the rest of the system.  If some functionality is already there in the OS, why not leverage it?

4) Threads pose a particular problem - they could be in any state.  They may be running on a different core than the thread that initiates app close or may be blocked on a system call.  While it's very easy for the OS to ensure that all threads are terminated before releasing any memory, closing handles etc, it's very difficult to stop such threads in a safe and reliable manner from user code.

5) Performance-sapping memory-managers are not the only way of detecting leaks. If large objects, (eg. network buffers), are pooled, it's easy to tell if any leak during run-time without relying on 3rd-party memory-managers that issue a leak report on app close. An intensive memory-checker like Valgrind my actually cause system problems by affecting the overall timing.

6) Empirically, every app I've eve written for Windows that has no explicit shutdown code has closed immediately and completely when the user clicks on the 'red cross' border icon.  This incudes busy, complex IOCP servers running on multicore boxes with thousands of connected clients.

7) Assuming that a reasonable test phase has been done - one that includes load/soak testing - it's not difficult to differentiate an app that is leaking from one that chooses to not free memory that it is using at close time.  Colander-apps will show memory/handles/whatever always increasing with run time.

8) Small, occasional leaks that are not obvious are not worth spending a huge amount of time on.  Most Windows boxes are restarted every month anyway, (Patch Tuesday).

9) Opaque libraries are often written by developers like me and so will generate spurious 'leak reports' on shutdown anyway.

Designing/writing/debugging/testing shutdown code solely to clean up a memory-report is an expensive luxury I can well do without:)

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your experience!

Answer (score 0):

You should determine that for each object individually. If an object requires special actions to be taken upon cleanup (such as flushing a buffer to disk), this will not happen unless you explicitly take care of it.