# What happens when interrupting a C program with a signal like SIGINT?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, signals

So this question came to my mind before completing my personal project. As a result of that I'm also wondering if I need to make any special operations to do cleanup before the process terminates (e.g freeing all the dynamically allocated memory) or is it handled by the Linux Kernel.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The OS will reclaim all memory allocated by a process after it terminates. But at the same time it is good practice to write code that cleans up as much as practically possible.

Comment: @kaylum: “Cleaning up” memory when a process exits is wasteful and is not good practice. It contributes to delays when an application is told to quit and spends several seconds or more doing useless work, irritating users and holding system resources unnecessarily when the system could be going on to do useful work. Certainly software ought to be designed to manage its memory carefully and not lose track of it inappropriately, but there is no need to “clean up” when terminating. (Some termination work does need to be done, such as flushing unwritten buffers, of course. But not freeing memory.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil careful when challenging the 'clean up and close gracefully' cargo-cult, else you will be joining me in the heretic's dungeon:)

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I agree that cleaning up on exit may waste recources. Especially if things are paged out to disk. But cleaning up also serves one important feature, it lets you prove that you have track of all the memory used. So during development I recommend to *always* clean up on exit. Having the habit to always create cleanup code, means that it is there when you need it. Adding it later when you need to track down a memory leak bug, is virtually impossible.

Comment: @HAL: Re “it lets you prove that you have track of all the memory used”: It does no such thing. If any `free` is omitted, there will be no error.

Comment: There are some downsides to cleanup code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12002019/758133

Comment: @EricPostpischil, "If any `free` is omitted, there will be no error." That is why we use tools like valgrind during development, so that any missing `free` gets turned into errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your process exits, the Linux system will reclaim all of its resources, regardless of how your process exits.

If you allow `SIGINT` to terminate your process, rather than catching it and handling it, buffers may remain unflushed. If you want your program to finish any work cleanly before exiting, you need to design your program so that it can catch the signal and do any desired termination work.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. May I ask what do you mean by unflushed buffer ?

Comment: @yankh18: By default, C standard output is line buffered.  Buffering means the C library keeps the data in an internal array.  Line buffering means the data is only written to the underlying device or file when a newline is encountered.  For example, if you do `printf("Hello, "); sleep(5); printf("World!\n");` you won't see the first part before the five-second delay, because the C library internally buffered it ("unflushed").  You'd need to do say `printf("Hello, "); fflush(stdout); sleep(5); printf("World!\n");`.  Buffering affects not only the standard streams, but all FILEs you have open.